# Action bar produces pointer exception warning?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Invocation of the method `actionbar.functions()` may produce

```
java. lang.null pointer exception
```

I am using Android Studio beta. My min SDK version 15+. By default it is holo, right?

themes.xml

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/app_theme</item>
</style>
```

In manifest

```
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
```